# A property of the a class refers to the same class. How to manage the instance

Tags: c#, class, reference

I have the following code in my module:

```
Class Studentdatabase
{
public List <student> studentslist;
public void UpdateStudentDetailsinlist();
}


Class student
{
public string name;
public int age;
public int marks;
public student friend;
}
```

My module populates this database with data and this database will be used by another module.

```
studentslist [0]
name - Trevor
age -12
marks - 33
friend - 
    name - Sam
    age - 12
    marks - 45

studentslist [1]
name - Warren
age -13
marks - 63
friend - 
    name - Sam
    age - 12
    marks - 45

studentslist [2]
name - Sam
age -12
marks - 45
friend - null
```

My requirement is that if the studentlist [2] (Sam) is updated with marks as 48, Automatically the marks of Sam in studentslist [0] and studentslist [1] must be updated (reverse also).
How can this be implemented in the module?

Comment: what are you passing into the update method?

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey it looks like he is not passing anything at least not at the signature of the method: `public void UpdateStudentDetailsinlist();` Maybe use the reference to same object in each list?

Comment: Yeah I figured this was incomplete, as the Student is missing identifiers such as Ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as follows.

```
class StudentContext
{
    public List<Student> Studentslist { get; set; }

    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (null == Studentslist)
        {
            Studentslist = new List<Student>();
        }
        Studentslist.Add(student);
    }

    public void AddFriend(Student student,Student friendStudent)
    {
        Studentslist.Where(x => x.StudentId == student.StudentId).FirstOrDefault().Friend = friendStudent;
    }
}

class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
    public Student Friend { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.StudentId = 1;
        student1.Name = "A";
        student1.Marks = 100;

        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.StudentId = 2;
        student2.Name = "AB";
        student2.Marks = 10;

        StudentContext studentContext = new StudentContext();
        studentContext.AddStudent(student1);
        studentContext.AddStudent(student2);
        studentContext.AddFriend(student1, student2);

        student1.Marks = 50;
        student2.Marks = 77;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you need an identifier(of some kind - Guid,int etc.) which will be your primary key.

The actual value that needs to be saved in the database is the identifier of the friend.

```
Class student
{
   public int id;
   public string name;
   public int age;
   public int marks;
   public int StudentFriendId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same reference and it will be reflected at all places.

Example:

```
Student sam = new Student();
sam.Marks = 45;
//... other sam properties


Student warren = new Student();
// initialize all waren properties
waren.friend = sam;

// do same for trevor
Student trevor = new Student();


List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(sam);
students.Add(waren);
students.Add(trevor);

//Now waren/trevor holds same student reference which is in student list so any change in sam will be reflected in friend of waren/trevor
sam.Marks = 48;// reflected at all 3 places.
```

If you want to change the behavior, you can either change `Student` to struct (from class) or assign copy/clone of sam to friend of waren/trevor

Answer (score 1):

you should follow following structure and put id instead of whole instnce in friend

```
Class Studentdatabase
{
  public List <student> studentslist;
  public void UpdateStudentDetailsinlist();
}


   Class student
   {
      public int id,
      public string name;
      public int age;
      public int marks;
      public int friend; // it will contain id of that friend in student
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost and unique identifier is a must, something like an integer `id` field. If `Name` property is good enough, that will do but that generally is not good idea (which means only one student can have a particular name). Some options:

1. As Tilak says, updating on the same reference works.
2. In case you can't be sure about that, one idea is to force maintain a single reference through out the application for every unique student (id).

   ```
   class Student
   {
       //ideally properties
       public int id
       public string name;
       public int age;
       public int marks;
       public Student friend; 

       static readonly Dictionary<int, Student> students = new Dictionary<int, Student>();

       //a static factory method with whatever definition, but int id is a must
       public static Student Create(int id, string name, int age, int marks)
       {
           Student student;
           return students.TryGetValue(id, out student) 
                ? student 
                : new Student(id, name, age, marks)     
       }

       //private constructor, with whatever definition.
       private Student(int id, string name, int age, int marks)
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` gives it better meaning.
3. In case the above is too much on memory and updating happens directly to the database, you can avoid a property/field `friend` on `Student` class but provide a method to query from db. Something like:

   ```
   class Student
   {
       //ideally properties
       public int id
       public string name;
       public int age;
       public int marks;

       private int friendId; //private it is

       public Student GetFriend()
       {
           return db.GetStudent(friendId);
       }
   }
   ```